# Iterate through all the controls of a different application?

Tags: .net

I am using .NET 2.0.

How can I iterate through all controls of a different / foreign WinForm application?

Comment: Is it a form you started yourself or is it one that happens to be running concurrently while your application is running?

Comment: Are you definitely bound to .NET 2.0? In .NET 3.5 you could use the  `System.Windows.Automation` namespace, otherwise you must stick to P/Invoke and fiddling with Spy++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use [enum child windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) api function the windows classes should be able to be mapped to specific winforms controls.